# Calling wmctrl after zenity in shellscript does not work

Tags: linux, shell, linux-mint, zenity

I have this *very simple* shellscript, I need to move one dialog created with zenity

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --progress --title="Progress" --auto-close --no-cancel --text="Updating..."
wmctrl -r "Progress" -e 0,0,0,-1,-1
```

But it does not work, if you try the commands in other shell works properly, but not in the script.

Comment: which error it is showing??

Comment: @rups isn't showing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your script is written suggests that
1. zenity is executed and displays a window, bash waits for it to finish
2. next, wmctrl is executed, and is unable to find zenity since its window is already closed

You should add an ampersand ("&" symbol) to the end of your zenity line (and perhaps sleep for a while to let zenity create the window) before you can call wmctrl.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this way, but still not working, this issue is very annoying because it's suposed to work properly...

Comment: Did you use a sleep command between the two lines to make sure zenity has finished displaying the window by the time wmctrl is called? Sorry if it sounds like I'm asking the same thing twice, I just don't think my answer states the importance of a pause well enough.